# If I buy a Mac Mini from the US, can I use it in the UK?

Tags: mac

I'm assuming that I can (and buy a UK keyboard separate), and that I just need to find a UK power adapter. Is this correct? If so, is eBay the best place, or can I get one direct from Apple somehow?

Comment: Yes to the first question. Computers don't really care where in the world they are as long as you're using the correct adapter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Macs have almost always* used auto-switching universal power supplies, so all you need is the right AC (mains) cord or plug. The connector between the AC cord and the power supply is usually a standard connector, so you don't necessarily have to buy a cable from Apple. If you do want to buy a cable from Apple, just go to [store.apple.com](http://store.apple.com/).

Probably the most significant regional difference today is the Wi-Fi card, which may default to scanning US FCC-approved channels, which may mean it won't find an AP on channel 12 or 13 in 2.4GHz because it doesn't think it should scan them, and it may transmit probe requests on channels (149-165) that it's not supposed to transmit on in ETSI-regulated places like the UK. But as soon as it sees an AP publishing the UK country code, it'll switch into UK mode for that session. No one really cares if a few expats and visitors have equipment that occasionally transmits a frame on the wrong channel, as long as no business is commercially mass-importing devices that break the local rules.

**almost always: Well, some Power Mac G3 and G4 towers from a decade ago might have had manually-switched power supplies. See [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1981).*

Comment: Great answer! :) Could you point me to the AC adapter on the UK Apple site? I can't seem to find it... http://store.apple.com/uk/search?find=mac+mini+power

Comment: Hmm, does the latest model have an adapter? I see this cable on eBay: http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Apple-Mac-Mini-2012-Power-Cable-/200749057845?pt=UK_Computing_Apple_Mac_Accessories&hash=item2ebd938735#ht_500wt_1202

Comment: @nbolton The latest model uses a standard [IEC 60320](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320) C7 non-polarized connector, like you've probably seen many times but never known the official standard designation of. On that Wikipedia page, be sure to look at the non-polarized version of the connector on the C7/C8 row of the table.